# Closed set implies non-open set?

Tags: general-topology

Given $X$ a metric space and $E$ is a strict subset of $X$ that's non-empty and is closed in $X$, is it true that $E$ is not open?

My guess is no, considering I can form the metric space $X=(-1,1) \cup 2$ and then $E = (-1,1)$. Every limit point of $E$ in $X$ is a point of $E$ making $E$ closed in $X$, however, every point in $E$ is clearly an interior point as well, so $E$ is open in $X$.

Does anyone have anymore insight into this?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: If metric space $X$ is **connected** and $E$ is nonempty proper subset of $X$, then openness of $E$ implies $E$ is not closed.

If $X$ is topological space, existence of clopen nonempty proper subset of $X$ is equivalent to $X$ is not connected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sets which are both closed and open in a topological space are called [clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set) and the link gives several examples.

Comment: i totally racked my brain for 2 days thinking about this, glad i havent gone totally insane yet :P

Comment: @DanZimm It's only a matter of time.

Comment: I'll be accepting as soon as SE lets me

Answer (score 4):

**Depend on the metric space $X$.**

> **Example 1** $X$ is $\mathbb R$ with usual topology. $E=[0,1]\subset X$, then $E$ is not open.
>
> **Example 2** $X$ is a discrete space. It always a metric space. Every set $E \subset X$ is open and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $\mathbb{R}\setminus{\{1,-1\}}$, $E:=(-1,1)$ is both open and closed in it